# extracting a string based on regex using xslt 1.0

Tags: string, xslt-1.0, strip

I need to remove a particular string from a tag using xslt 1.0. The string is random and can appear anywhere.The only way to identify the string is that it is followed by either "tt" or "Tt" or "tt." or "Tt."

Can anybody help me with the code snippet which i can use to achieve this.

For example

```
      <Page>9 tt., 407-415</Page>
      Expected output (remove 9tt.)
      <Page>, 407-415</Page>

      <Page>425 Tt (approx.)</Page>
      Expected output (remove 425 Tt)
      <Page> (approx.)</Page>

      <Page>055302, 8 tt.</Page>
      Expected output(remove 8Tt.)
      <Page>055302, </Page>
```

Comment: There is no native regex support in XSLT 1.0 - and it looks like you really need it here. Which XSLT 1.0 processor will you be using? It might  support regex as an extension.

Comment: I will be using the XSLT processor which comes with IBM Datapower system.

Comment: AFAIK, it supports the [EXSLT regex extenstion functions](http://exslt.org/regexp/index.html).